# Как написать регулярное выражение Java для выделения подстроки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка допустим "2.2*2+3/4+2" возможно ли написать такое регулярное выражение которое будет выделять подстороку типа число * число и число / число? 
то есть что бы в результате вышло String[] s = {"2.2*2","3/4"}.

и какой функцией резать исходную строку? пробовал split не выходит. Возможно это можно получить другим каким-то образом, не через регулярные выражения?

Очень надеюсь на ответ! Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RegexDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "2.2*2+3/4+2";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(\\*|\\/)\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(m.find()) {
            matches.add(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```